# Contador y Media C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy realizando un programa en el que solicito los datos de N estudiantes tales como su nombre, edad, peso y estatura, quiero conocer la media del peso de los estudiantes, cuantos estudiantes poseen la misma estatura y cual es esa estatura.

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

        namespace examen
        {
         class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int cant, i=0, j=0,cont =0;
        double suma = 0,promedio =0;


        Console.Write("Ingrese el numero de alumnos que desea ingresar: ");
        cant = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        string[] nombres = new string[cant];
        int[] edad = new int[cant];
        double[] peso = new double[cant];
        float[] estatura = new float[cant];

        for (i = 0; i < cant; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.Write("Ingrese el nombre para el " + (i+1) + " estudiante: ");
            nombres[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.Write("Ingrese la edad perteneciente al estudiante " + nombres[i] + ": ");
            edad[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.Write("Ingrese el peso perteneciente al estudiante " + nombres[i] + ": ");
            peso[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            suma+=peso[i];
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.Write("Ingrese la estatura perteneciente al estudiante " +nombres[i] + ": ");
            estatura[i] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             if (estatura[i] == estatura[i])
            {
                cont++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("El peso promedio de los estudiantes es: " + suma/cant);
        Console.WriteLine("La cantidad de estudiantes que tienen la misma estatura son: " + cont);
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
    }
    }
```

por el momento tengo este código y presento dos problemas

1-al momento de calcular la media, el separador decimal (punto) no se imprime correctamente (posición en donde tendría que estar)

2-la variable "cont" es la encargada de acumular las veces que una estatura de un estudiante se repite con la de otro estudiante y aunque he creado una condicion "if" para ello, siempre me imprime que la cantidad de estudiantes que tienen la misma estatura es igual a la cantidad de estudiantes a ingresar por el usuario

en cuanto a la parte de imprimir cual estatura es la que se repite entre los estudiantes me gustaría primero solucionar los problemas antes planteados para luego imprimir esa estatura

Comment: He tratado de entender tu código y lo que buscas; el promedio lo veo trabajando bien, pero el uso de CONT, cómo debería funcionar?? si tengo 5 estaturas: 175, 180, 175, 180, 175 ... qué debería de aparecer: 2?? o 3? Ya que muestras: "Número de estudiantes con la misma edad" (lo veo como problema de lógica)

Comment: En primera instancia tomando como base tu ejemplo, dadas esas 5 estaturas lo que busco es que imprima: 3 estudiantes poseen las misma estatura y esa estatura es "175", 2 estudiantes poseen la misma estatura y esa estatura es "180"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq tiene la opción Distinct() que te puede ayudar a encontra valores únicos.
Prueba con esto.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace examen
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int cant, i = 0, j = 0, cont = 0;
            double suma = 0, promedio = 0;

            Console.Write("Ingrese el numero de alumnos que desea ingresar: ");
            cant = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            string[] nombres = new string[cant];
            int[] edad = new int[cant];
            double[] peso = new double[cant];

            List<double> estaturas = new List<double>();
            for (i = 0; i < cant; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("Ingrese el nombre para el " + (i + 1) + " estudiante: ");
                nombres[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("Ingrese la edad perteneciente al estudiante " + nombres[i] + ": ");
                edad[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("Ingrese el peso perteneciente al estudiante " + nombres[i] + ": ");
                peso[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                suma += peso[i];
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("Ingrese la estatura perteneciente al estudiante " + nombres[i] + ": ");
                estaturas.Add(float.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("El peso promedio de los estudiantes es: " + suma / cant);
            //Console.WriteLine("La cantidad de estudiantes que tienen la misma estatura son: " + cont);

            var listaEstaturas = estaturas.Distinct().ToArray();
            foreach (var elemento in listaEstaturas)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine(estaturas.Count(e => e == elemento)
                     + " estudiantes poseen las misma estatura  " + elemento);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Un breve resumen:**

La línea  `var listaEstaturas = estaturas.Distinct().ToArray();` creo una variable llamada listaEstaturas con valores únicos (quita los repetidos).

Luego `estaturas.Count(e => e == elemento)` cuenta las veces que se repite.
E imprimo esos valores con:

```
       foreach (var elemento in listaEstaturas)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine(estaturas.Count(e => e == elemento)
                 + " estudiantes poseen las misma estatura  " + elemento);
        }
```

Comment: con la opción Distinc() me funciono pero ¿podrías resumirme un poco como va ese proceso? Gracias

Comment: Es una solucion viable.. pero en los casos de ejercicios para aprender siempre se recomienda a quien pregunta que aprenda el algoritmo primero, porque si no, solo depende de funciones que no sabe lo que hacen...